# Convert the string of date and time (2018-04-13T20:00:00.0400) into date string (April 13, 2018) in Kotlin

Tags: android, datetime, exception, kotlin, runtime-error

I want to convert the DateTime string like "2018-04-13T20:00:00.0400" into "April 13, 2018". I have used the code

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd", Locale.getDefault())
val startDate = sdf.parse(data.start_time)
```

but with this code, my app crashes. Any help regarding this

Log is showing this

```
2018-10-11 16:44:56.948 20482-21021/? E/NowController: Failed to access data from EntryProvider. ExecutionException.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.eA(SourceFile:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:23)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.l.get(SourceFile:2)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:49)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
 Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.ar.az(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.ap(SourceFile:7)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.run(SourceFile:32)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bt.execute(SourceFile:3)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.b(SourceFile:275)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.addListener(SourceFile:135)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.b(SourceFile:3)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:16)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:13)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:47)
```

Comment: share your crash logcat.

Comment: @HemantParmar how to get the logcat of the crash ?

Comment: Google it!, you will see lots of post!

Comment: Try out this answer, it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674753/9185192

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: First step is to paste your exception messge into your search engine, in this case `Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3`. And in this case it will give you a number of hits (if not, change to another search engine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes, never the terrible legacy classes.

Here is Java syntax (I have not yet learned Kotlin).

```
LocalDateTime                             // Represent a date with time-of-day but lacking offset-from-UTC or time zone. As such, this does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.
.parse( "2018-04-13T20:00:00.0400" )      // Parse an input string in standard ISO 8601 format. Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.toLocalDate()                            // Extract the date-only portion without the time-of-day. Still no time zone or offset-from-UTC. Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.format(                                  // Generate text representing the value of that `LocalDate` object.
    DateTimeFormatter                     // Define a pattern to use in generating text.
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )  // Automatically localize, specifying how long/abbreviated…
    .withLocale( Locale.US )              // … and what human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.
)                                         // Return a `String`.
```

> April 13, 2018

For earlier Android, see bullets at bottom below.

## Use *java.time*

> convert the DateTime string like "2018-04-13T20:00:00.0400" into "April 13, 2018".

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

First, parse your input string. But what is that `.0400` on the end? Perhaps a fractional second? But conventionally the milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds are displayed in groups of 3 digits. So your four digits here is odd. Perhaps an offset-from-UTC? Four digits is right for that, for hours and minutes with leading zero. But there is no *plus* or *minus* sign to indicate ahead-of or behind UTC. So I'll go with the fractional second.

Your input lacks any indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`. Your string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes.

```
String input = "2018-04-13T20:00:00.0400";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-04-13T20:00:00.040

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() :
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-04-13

Generate text representing that date's value. Let *java.time* automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( Locale.US );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

> April 13, 2018

**Beware:** A `LocalDateTime` object is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Lacking any offset-from-UTC or time zone means it represent a range of *potential* moments, along a range of about 26-27 hours (the current range of time zones around the globe). If the input string were implicitly intended to represent a moment in the wall-clock time of some region, you should apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object before extracting a `LocalDate`. This has been shown many times before on Stack Overflow.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

A fixed version of the above, since your Date input doesn't have a Z in it. And their output format doesn't match yours. I would suggest reading the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
that way you can modify the responses as needed.

```
fun convertISOTimeToDate(isoTime: String): String? {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    var convertedDate: Date? = null
    var formattedDate: String? = null
    try {
        convertedDate = sdf.parse(isoTime)
        formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd,yyyy").format(convertedDate)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return formattedDate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Syntax LocaleDateTime.parse (Examples) =>

```
val date = LocalDateTime
    .parse(q.ADDDATE)
    .toLocalDate()
    .format(
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
    )

val dateView = date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format in correct way. Try below code you should convert from ISO date format to normal date format.Thanks

```
fun convertISOTimeToDate(isoTime: String): String? {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
        var convertedDate: Date? = null
        var formattedDate: String? = null
        try {
            convertedDate = sdf.parse(isoTime)
            formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy" + "\n" + " hh:mm:ss a").format(convertedDate)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return formattedDate
    }
```